# how to set height and width of nvd3 chart

Tags: nvd3.js

I'm trying to set the width and height of a nvd3 multi bar chart programmatically using

```
chart.width(600);
chart.height(400);
```

See the example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hPgyq/20/

As you can see this really messes up the chart. I know I can do this is CSS with:

```
#chart svg {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

but I thought this was also possible using the width() and height() functions on the chart. Am I doing something wrong here or am I mis-using the two functions?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes it is possible, like you have specified the width & height of the chart, you have to use the `d3.select` and set its width & height attribute.

Changes to the code are below and there is a version of the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shabeer90/zmtN5/)

```
function visualizeData(data) {
    nv.addGraph(function() {
        var width = 600, height = 400;
        chart = nv.models.multiBarChart().x(function(d) {
            return d.x;
        }).y(function(d) {
            return d.y;
        }).color(['#aec7e8', '#7b94b5', '#486192']).stacked(true)
        //.margin({top:150,right:150,bottom:150,left:150})
        .width(width).height(height);

        chart.multibar.hideable(false);

        chart.xAxis.showMaxMin(true).tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

        chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

        d3.select('#chart svg').datum(data).transition().duration(500).call(chart).style({ 'width': width, 'height': height });

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        return chart;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see that your modifications do work. But can you please explain why the width/height needs to be specified in 2 separate places? It seems redundant and cumbersome. I love the NV3 work, but this seems like an undesirable aspect of the API. I'm sure there's a good reason I'm not understanding. Could you please educate me here? In dc.js for example, you set the width/height in one place only and dc.js takes care of the rest for you.

Comment: I believe the calls to `width` and `height` are setting the width and height properties of the chart, whereas the calls to `attr` with the width and height properties are setting the width and height of the svg the chart is being drawn onto.

Comment: nvd3 is complex

Answer (score 0):

For the [AngularJs](https://angularjs.org/) version ([angular-nvd3](https://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/)), I had to add the `height` either in chart options and as an attribute:

**chart.html**

```html
<nvd3 options='vm.chartOptions' data='vm.chartData' height="250" config="vm.chartConfig">
    </nvd3>
```

**chart.controller.js**

```js
vm.chartOptions = {
    chart : {
        height : 250,
        type : "pieChart",
        donut : true,
        showLegend : false,
        //The rest of the configuration
};
```

As it is told in the comments, first seems to control the height of the inner svg and the second does the global chart height.