# d3/nvd3: how can I set the size of ticks on x-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, nvd3.js

I would like to have x-axis ticks with only around 10px height. Per default every tick has 100% height of the chart-container. 
How can I achieve this - setting a css-parameter won't work because the ticks are getting calcuated and the height is set as svg-attribute?!

Is there any kind of parameter in nvd3 I could set? Or do I have to do this via d3-code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set height and width of nvd3 chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474988/how-to-set-height-and-width-of-nvd3-chart)

Answer (score 0):

I believe tickSize is the property you are looking for. You can define it on your axis. This property is inherited from d3. Dont have much info on how it can be used but the community documentation mentions it here : [Documentation](https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html)

Hope this helps a bit.